# Execute a literal string as a SQL statement - placement of single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I have the following SQL string pulls data from a ODBC Progress Database via a linked server. **This query works fine.**

```
SELECT * 
INTO [TABLE] 
FROM 
OPENQUERY
(
"ODBC DRIVER",
'SELECT CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."ACCESS_CODE" AS VARCHAR(20)) AS "ACCESS-CODE"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."DESCRIPTION" AS VARCHAR(60)) AS "DESCRIPTION"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."ORG_CODE" AS VARCHAR(16)) AS "ORG_CODE"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."POINTS" AS INT) AS "POINTS" 
FROM SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY" with (nolock)'
)
```

However, I would like to convert this to a **literal string** so that I can execute this from a stored procedure using `exec sp_executesql`.

However, I'm having trouble with correct placement of apostrophes so that `exec sp_executesql` can read it as a properly formed SQL statement.

Could someone please show me where to add additional apostrophes to the above statement so that it will work with exec sp_excutesql?

Thanks!

**Edits for clarity:**

1. `With (nolock)` is fine for the above
2. The purpose of the above is to loop over a number of SQL statements in a list to import data from a Progress DB.

Comment: Slight detour...I notice you are using the NOLOCK hint here. Are you cool with randomly getting missing and/or duplicate rows? In other words, is it ok if your query is mostly accurate most of the time? You might want to read up a bit about that hint to make sure you fully understand it. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Why do you think you need to run this as dynamic sql?

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks - updated main question for clarity

Comment: I think @Sean's questions about the use of the `NOLOCK` hint were meant to be rhetorical. :)

Comment: My comments about NOLOCK are because in my career I have seen it used over and over saying "dirty reads are fine" without that person understanding that it is much more sinister than that.

Comment: What I still don't understand though is why you need to execute this as dynamic sql. You don't have to run this as dynamic sql from inside a stored procedure, unless the target of the insert is dynamic. If that is the case I would question that something else is going on there.

Comment: Thanks Sean, both good points to take on board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to escape the ' characters with ''

```
SELECT * 
INTO [TABLE] 
FROM 
OPENQUERY
(
"ODBC DRIVER",
''SELECT CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."ACCESS_CODE" AS VARCHAR(20)) AS "ACCESS-CODE"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."DESCRIPTION" AS VARCHAR(60)) AS "DESCRIPTION"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."ORG_CODE" AS VARCHAR(16)) AS "ORG_CODE"
,CAST(SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY"."POINTS" AS INT) AS "POINTS" 
FROM SCHEMA."AB_ACCESSIBILITY" with (nolock)''
)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the above